# Can't connect to rails server on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtual-machine

TL;DR I randomly can't connect to a local Rails server and the problem follows me across computers.

I'm working on a website that uses Rails.

I started my work on an Arch VM using VirtualBox. Inside that VM I could start up `rails s` and connect to the website at 0.0.0.0:3000 no problem. I was using Chrome from inside the VM to connect to the website.

I added one line of code. I saved the file but did NOT commit or stage. Couldn't connect anymore. [image]

Erased the line I and saved again. Still couldn't connect.

Deleted the folder the site was in. Recloned the repo. Reran the setup script (installs things like rvm, node.js, and rails; see end of post). No luck.

Exited the VM, booted up an Ubuntu install, cloned the repo again (this time into an NTFS drive because that's where I have the most space), ran setup again. Nope. [image]

What was weird is that even though the rails server started, I appeared to not have rails on my system. [image: Going off the rails]

For some reason, node installed, rvm and rails did not.

Moved to ~, cloned repo yet again, ran setup again. Same deal. Don't have rails. Although again, `rails s` in the setup script ran but I couldn't connect in the browser.

Installed rvm, installed bundler, ran `bundle install --without production staging` just like in the script, and ran the `rake`s. `rails s`. Still can't connect.

Nmap says I'm accepting connections on port 3000.

So overflowers, any ideas on how a local connectivity problem could follow me across a computer with no changes to the code base? Or how things like rails can install and not install?

Setup script:

```
#vagrant
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

#Dependencies
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev -y 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
#install rvm and ruby
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm 
echo "" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "# Auto-Generated source for RVM" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
rvm install 2.0
rvm use 2.0 --default
ruby -v

#Set up repo
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
gem install bundler
bundle install --without production staging
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
rails s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly connecting to your rails server.

> => Rails x.x.x application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000

The line above states the ip address the server is listening on.

To connect to the server located in the same machine use

```
localhost:3000
```

If your VM is bridged to your LAN and you want to access it from the host computer, first get the adapter ip using `ifconfig` and then use it like

```
ADAPTER_IP:3000
```

Answer (score 1):

well, you should type `127.0.0.1:3000` or `localhost:3000` in the browser or terminal.

Listen 0.0.0.0:3000 means listen all IP addresses in the local machine.

Comment: Thanks! Both of those work. I still have no idea what's going on with the installations, but now I have a development environment (I think).

Comment: Oddly enough, 127.0.0.1 and localhost connect even though the server is on 0.0.0.0. Do you know why that is?

Comment: You got it wrong, the server is not on 0.0.0.0, it is listening to connections coming in from that IP... and 0.0.0.0 means every IP.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I'm on Vagrant and I can't connect to my Rails server in browser. It just says connection refused!